# PSQL: add case / if statement to `returning` statement

Tags: case, psql

I want to do the insert in all cases, but I only want to return `ID` if `my_array` (type `varchar[]`)only has one element.

I've tried something like this:

```
with x_array_items as (
        select id from unnest(my_array) as id
    )
insert into table (name, description)
select name, description
from other_table ot,
x_array_items xa
where ot.id = xa.id
returning (case when array_length(my_array, 1) = 1 is false then id else null end) into my_variable;
```

But I'm getting a `query returned more than one row` - is there a solution?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Even if you return NULL in your `RETURNING` clause, that will still be more than one NULLs if the `INSERT` inserts more than one row, which causes the error.

You could use more `WITH` clauses to do what you want:

```
WITH ids AS (
   INSERT INTO tab (name, description)
   SELECT name, description
   FROM other_table ot
   WHERE ARRAY[ot.id] <@ my_array
   RETURNING id
),
id_agg AS (
   SELECT min(id) AS id,
          count(*) AS c
   FROM ids
)
SELECT CASE WHEN c = 1
            THEN id
       END
       INTO my_variable
FROM id_agg;
```